# How to get/extract own source code for interaction

Tags: ios, xcode

Is there currently any way, without Private APIs, or with, to extract the source code as an object to be able to interact with it, in the form of a `UIWebView` for example, or a `UITextView` or just a long string?

Scenario:

There is an enterprise developer. A company wants all IT managers to be able to see all source code, in real time, or otherwise, for feedback and/or interaction. Things like post-it style comments, or drawing will be left in areas that need improvement/alteration, etc. All managers should be able to see methods/functions and essentially all implementations as is.

I have a few ideas on how I want to implement this, but just thought it would be good to get some outside suggestions, because brainstorming never hurts. Is there any thoughts on where I should be looking for simplicity?